# Linq searching list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this class:

```
public class ExamReviewRequested
{
    public List<ExamReviewRequest> Reviews { get; set;}
}
```

It's reviews property has a list of this class:

```
public class ExamReviewRequest
{
    public string EventCode { get; set; }
    public bool Requested { get; set; }
}
```

How do I search for a specific EventCode and return the selected ExamReviewRequest with that EventCode using LINQ? In my View, both these (Row.EventCode has the value I want to search for):

```
ExamReviewRequest er = ViewBag.ExamReviews.Single(x => x.EventCode == Row.EventCode)

ExamReviewRequest er = ViewBag.ExamReviews.Reviews.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EventCode == Row.EventCode)
```

return this error:

```
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type
```

I've looked at several posts concerning this subject but can't make any of them work.

Comment: This isn't the kind of thing you should be doing with the viewbag.  This points out a challenge in your architecture...

Comment: Why did this get down-voted? It's a fair question for someone who's unfamiliar with LINQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you assign `ExamReviews` to the `ViewBag` they become a `dynamic` object with no type setting. The error message is telling you that you need to cast it first to use Linq.

**What you could do**

I can't see where you assign `ViewBag.ExamReviews` so if it's of type `IEnumerable<ExamReviewRequest>` then:

```
var examReviews = (IEnumerable<ExamReviewRequest>)ViewBag.ExamReviews
var examReviewRequest = examReviews.Single(x => x.EventCode == Row.EventCode)
```

Or if it's of type `ExamReviewRequested` then:

```
var examReviews = (ExamReviewRequested)ViewBag.ExamReviews
var examReviewRequest = examReviews.Requests.Single(x => x.EventCode == Row.EventCode)
```

**What you should do**

You shouldn't assign the `List<ExamViewRequest>` / `ExamReviewRequested` to the `ViewBag`. This way you could do:

```
// Code to set model previous
var examReviewRequested = model.ExamReviews.Single(x => x.EventCode == Row.EventCode);
```

Where `model` is of type `ExamReviewRequested`

Comment: Getting this at runtime `Unable to cast object of type 'MyPage.Models.ExamReviewRequested' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[MyPage.Models.ExamReviewRequest]'.`

Comment: What is the type of `MyPage.Models.ExamReviewRequested`

Comment: You should cast `ExamReviewRequested` to `ExamReviewRequested` and `ExamReviewRequested.Reviews` to `List<ExamReviewRequest>`. Is `ViewBag.ExamReviews` of type `ExamReviewRequested`?

Comment: Problem was I should have done this: `ViewBag.ExamReviews = ExamRevReq.Reviews` instead of this: `ViewBag.ExamReviews = ExamRevReq`

Comment: Ah, I'm glad you sorted it @MB34. I edited my answer in any case

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the type of `ViewBag.ExamReviews` is `dynamic`, so the compiler doesn't know what to do with your lambda expression. Just cast that part so you can use LINQ on it as normal:

```
var requests = (IEnumerable<ExamReviewRequest>) ViewBag.ExamReviews;
var singleRequest = requests.Single(x => x.EventCode == Row.EventCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the key to this issue is that ViewBag is of type "dynamic". This means that the expression `ViewBag.ExamReviews` is also dynamic. You must cast away the dynamic to use linq agaist it.
I'm guessing at the types here, because I don't have enough information.

```
((IEnumerable<ExamReviewRequest>)ViewBag.ExamReviews).Single(x => x.EventCode == Row.EventCode)
```